# How am I able to check if the /authentication route is used?

Tags: authentication, feathersjs

I am building a FeathersJS app with authentication and authorization.
I handle the authorization manually with before hooks on almost every route besides the "/authentication" route because of course you want to leave this route unprotected so everyone is able to authenticate/login.
My problem is that when I call the /authentication route it also calls the /users route which is protected. Of course this is a problem which often occurs because this route is called by multiple other routes but I filter these calls in the authorization hook with

```
if(context.params.providers) {...}
```

When I call the /authentication route the hook is called with the /users route and a provider is set, which should not be like that if I am right.
Is there a way to filter this /authentication route?

Answer (score 1):

The current authentication code assumes you can call the `users` `get` with an external provider (mostly to make sure the user returned to the client has any `after` hooks applied to filter/prune sensitive data.

Note that the call feathers makes to get the user with the provider set also includes the user in the params, so you can use that user context to make authorization decisions (e.g. allow a user to retrieve his/her own user record).

https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/blob/master/packages/authentication/src/jwt.ts#L103